# Deterministic Fourier Deconvolution

Tags: python, numpy

I'm having a little trouble with doing a Fourier Deconvolution using numpy. I'm currently attempting this with a test case of 3 Gaussians so I know exactly what to expect at each end.

What I'm trying to recover is the input signal given the exact form of the filter and the output.

Here, I have used a naive constraint to suppress the high frequency ends setting it to zero (because the signals are all Gaussians in fourier space as well). I expected to recover my original input with a tiny bit of ringing due to this constraint.

```
#Dummy Case for Gaussian convolve with Gaussian

N = 128
x = np.arange(-5, 5, 10./(2 * N))
epsilon = 1e-18

def gaus(x,sigma):
    return 1./np.sqrt(2*np.pi)/sigma * np.exp(-(x * x)/(2 * sigma**2))

y_g = gaus(x,0.3)     #output gaussian blurred signal
y_b = gaus(x,0.1)     #gaussian blur filter
y_i = gaus(x,np.sqrt(0.3**2 - 0.1**2))   #og gaussian input

f_yg = np.fft.fft(y_g)    #fft the blur
f_yb = np.fft.fft(y_b)    #fft the filter
f_yi = np.fft.fft(y_i)

r_f = (np.fft.fftshift(f_yg)+epsilon)/(np.fft.fftshift(f_yb)+epsilon)      #deconvolve by division in fourier space
r_f[np.abs(x)>0.5] = 0    #naive constraint to remove the artifacts by knowing final form is gaussian

r_f = np.fft.ifftshift(r_f)

r_if = np.fft.ifft(r_f)
y_gf = np.fft.ifft(f_yg)
y_bf = np.fft.ifft(f_yb)
y_if = np.fft.ifft(f_yi)

plt.plot(x,y_if, label='fft true input')
plt.plot(x,r_if, label='fft recv. input')
plt.legend(framealpha=0.)
plt.show()
```

[image: gaussian]

Here the orange is the recovered input signal using the deconvolution of the output and the blur.

There are a few questions I have with this:

1. There is clearly a scaling issue. The only area where I can think that this may come in is when I applied the naive constraint. Should I renormalize in this step, knowing that 1/sqrt(N)*integral over my fourier space is equal to 1?
2. It looks like the position of the recovered Gaussian is messed up with half of the curve at either sides of the plot. Is this due to the division in Fourier space? How do I recover the original position (or have I done this completely wrong to begin with)

I've attached the script used to generate the two curves, the original input and recovered input in physical space.

Cheers,
Keven

EDIT: I should add I have no problem restoring the image using scipy.deconvolve + some small edits. This must mean my method here is somehow wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 ) As you correctly understood, the requirement for a scaling is related to the Discrete Fourier Transform. The best way to get it is to compute the deconvolution of two uniform unit signals. Their DFT is n 0 0 0 ...., where n is the number of points of the DFT. Hence the ratio r_f is 1 0 0 0 0 and its backward fft computed by `np.fft.ifft()` is 1/n 1/n 1/n ...
The correct signal resulting from the deconvolution should have been 1/T 1/T 1/T ..., where T=10. is the length of the frame.

As a consequence, the correct scaling to perform the deconvolution is `n/T= len(r_f)/10.`

```
r_if=r_if*len(r_if)/10.
```

2) The deconvoluted signal is translated by half a period. This is due to the fact that the gaussian kernel is centered on the middle of the frame. Simply shift the kernel by half a period and the problem is solved. The function `np.fft.fftshift()` can be applied to this end:

```
f_yb = np.fft.fft(np.fft.fftshift(y_b))    #fft the filter
```

EDIT: To investigate the reason for the translation, let's focus on the case of the deconvolution kernel being a very narrow gaussian distribution, nearly corresponding to Dirac distribution. Your input signal is a gaussian curve, centered at zero, the frame being sampled between -5 and 5. Similarly, the deconvolution kernel is a Dirac centered at zero. As a consequence, the deconvoluted signal must be identical to the input signal: a gaussian curve centered at zero. Nevertheless, the DFT as implemented in FFTW and consequently `np.fft.fft()` [is computed as that of a frame starting at 0 and ending at 10](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/The-1d-Discrete-Fourier-Transform-_0028DFT_0029.html#The-1d-Discrete-Fourier-Transform-_0028DFT_0029), sampled at points 10j/n where j is in [0..n-1], the frequencies in the Fourier space being k/10 where k in [0..n/2,-n/2+1..-1]. As a consequence, this DFT sees your signal as a gaussian centered at 5 and the deconvolution kernel as a Dirac centered at 5. The convolution of a function f(t) with a Dirac delta(t-t0) centered at t0 is simply the translated function f(t-t0). Hence, the result of the deconvolution as computed by `np.fft.fft()` is the input signal translated  by half a period. Since the input signal is centered at 0 in the [-5,5] frame, the output signal computed by `np.fft.fft()` is centered at -5 (or equivalently 5 due to periodicity). **Shifting the kernel resolves the mismatch between us thinking of the frame as [-5 5] and `np.fft.ifft()` handling it as if it were [0 10].**

Filters are often designed to reduce the effect of high-frequency noises. Deconvoluting therfore induce a potential magnification of high frequency noise. Screening the frequencies as you did is a potential solution. Notice that it is exactly equivalent to convoluting the signal with a particular filter!

In the range of tomographic reconstruction, the filtered backprojection algorithm requires applying a ramp filter, which dramatically inflate the high frequency noise. [Here](http://www.owlnet.rice.edu/~elec539/Projects97/cult/node4.html#SECTION00022000000000000000) is proposed a [Wiener filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_filter): this kind of filter can be designed to minimize the mean square error on the deconvoluted signal, given the SNR of the convoluted signal. It nevertheless require some assumption regarding the power spectral densities of the signal and noise.

Comment: AH! Thanks for your help. I realise where my issue with scaling lies.

I'm a little unsure about shifting the kernel. It definitely gives me back the result I'm expecting, but what is the justification of it?

Comment: You're welcome. I added a few line to the answer to investigate how this delay occurs.

Comment: I see, thanks for the additional comments! I realise I could also see this in the Discrete convolution equation in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution .